# Xcode not using the latest scheme version

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, cicd, xcodebuild

I am making a set of shell commands to generate a scheme for my iOS project. Now, when I create the scheme via Xcode GUI, the scheme generated uses the following version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Scheme
   LastUpgradeVersion = "1430"
   version = "1.7">
   <BuildAction
      parallelizeBuildables = "YES"
      buildImplicitDependencies = "YES">...
```

But when I do so on the script using the following:

```
    # create scheme
    scheme = Xcodeproj::XCScheme.new
    scheme.add_build_target(target)
    scheme.set_launch_target(target)
    scheme.save_as(proj_path, name, shared = true)
    proj.save
```

I get a different version.

```
<Scheme
   LastUpgradeVersion = "1300"
   version = "1.3">
```

Not sure if I'm missing anything on my commands. It is also noticeable that some properties on the 1.3 Version are not present on 1.7 version, particularly the `<MacroExpansion>` .

I am referencing the [XCScheme code from here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/blob/1-7-stable/lib/xcodeproj/scheme.rb) .

### EDIT

I have tried modifying the version through the same commands with:

```
scheme.last_upgrade_version = "1430"
scheme.version = "1.7"
```

but no luck so far.